# Rails 5.2 Simple Form Lambda Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

How do you use lambda functions for the data attributes in the input_html?

Let's say I have an **Author** model and a **Book** model. An **Author** can have many books, a **Book** can only have one author.

In the form for the **Author** model. I have the following -

```
<%= f.association :books, as: :check_boxes %>
```

I wanted to have a data attribute of the book's ISBN, like so -

```
<%= f.association :books, as: :check_boxes, input_html: {data: {isbn: lambda {|book| book.isbn} }} %>
```

But this does not work. Any ideas on how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's in simple_form's `input_html` API ... but you can always build the collection and pass it to the input like this (not tested):

```
<% collection = f.object.books.map { |book| [book.id, book.name, data: { isbn: book.isbn }] } %>
<%= f.association :foo, as: :check_boxes, collection: collection %>
```

You would probably need to initialize the collection in `Author#new`, or you may want to avoid using `f.association` and just use `f.input` once you're passing the `collection` ... but I hope this steers you toward the right direction. Let me know what's the winning option!

Comment: Thank you my good sir! This works perfectly well for my situation!

Comment: Thanks too, it works, but in my case, the returned array must contains first the label, then value, and all other thinks. So like [label, id, data]